# Is it safe to use exported Firebase as global object

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I had a discussion with my team. We were talking about should we export firebase object to use everywhere in our ReactJS project or do we have to use Redux to store the firebase object.

I've tried using export statement and it's working just fine.

```
import * as firebase from "firebase";

firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "xxxx",
  authDomain: "xxxxx",
  projectId: "xxx"
});

const firestore = firebase.firestore();

export { firebase, firestore };
```

Would it be better if I store firebase in state management or this approach is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not React developer, but I used Firebase with Vue. I know these two are completely different frameworks, but maybe this case will help you.

I installed Firebase plugin in Vue (*globally*). Then I used state management to store for example login state.

After installation (below):

```
import VueFire from 'vuefire'

Vue.use(VueFire)

new Vue({
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

I used Firebase reference to access it, for example:

```
methods: {
    addToDb: function () {
        this.$firebaseRefs.data.child('count').set(1);
    }
}
```

So in your case exporting will do, I guess.